# How to get All element url in wso2ESB

Tags: web-services, wso2, wso2-esb

I am working on wso2ESB version 4.9.
I have these URL:

```
http//192.168.0.1/getinfo/id=10&name=alice&from=AU$code=ddddd
http//192.168.0.1/adduser/id=11&name=bob&from=USA&tel=25644&city=newyork$code=ddddd
```

So i want  get all of element of URL and separate code and call web-service without code variable . My URL element is changing but always has code variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read query param string inside a [script mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Script+Mediator) (javascript). You can [read it like this](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2015/09/wso2-esb-how-to-url-encode-in-wso2-esb.html) and manipulate as per your need. Then you can [append it](http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-append-query-parameter-to-api.html) to the outgoing request.

```
mc.getProperty('QUERY_PARAMS')
```